# CSS: slide animation in quotes slideshow

Tags: javascript, css

I have a simple code that is changing on click slides.

I'm trying to make animation on an element with class "content" which may look like [this animation](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/21814379434665818/sent/?invite_code=bb14cbcc549045338d647b570d3e070f&sender=737323907652047207&sfo=1).

I tried it in this code where it does not look good.

Is there any option for how to make animation on an element with class "content" like is in link which I sent above?

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active");
  dots[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1f1;
}

/* Slides */
.mySlides {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0s linear;
}
.mySlides .content {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transform: translateX(-50px);
}
.mySlides.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
.mySlides.active .content {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}

/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */
.dot-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */
.dot.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */
q {
  font-style: italic;
}

/* Add a blue color to the author */
.author {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="content">
      <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
      <p class=" author ">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="content">
      <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
      <p class=" author ">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="content">
      <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
      <p class=" author ">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
    </div>
  </div>



  <a class="prev " onclick="plusSlides(-1) ">❮</a>
  <a class="next " onclick="plusSlides(1) ">❯</a>

</div>

<div class="dot-container ">
  <span class="dot " onclick="currentSlide(1) "></span>
  <span class="dot " onclick="currentSlide(2) "></span>
  <span class="dot " onclick="currentSlide(3) "></span>
</div>
```

Comment: At the moment you are bringing in the new text over the old. Do you want to gradually have the old text move off to the right as the new text comes in from the left (and vice versa when going forward in the slide show).

Comment: @AHaworth How can I do this in CSS?

Comment: @AHaworth is there a possible way to do that?