# CSS: slide animation between slides

Tags: javascript, html, css

My simple code makes the slider clickable and on click will change slides. Now there is animation between slides a little bit broken. The only element with class "content" is animated.

This animation now overlaps elements with class "content" and then slide only from left to right.

Is there any option for how to make animation on elements with class "content" like when it is sliding the current "content" will go a little bit left and new "content" will goes left too but at the same time?

Something like [this animation](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/21814379434665818/sent/?invite_code=bb14cbcc549045338d647b570d3e070f&sender=737323907652047207&sfo=1) I need to achieve.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active");
  dots[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1f1;
}

/* Slides */
.mySlides {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0s linear;
}
.mySlides .content {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transform: translateX(-50px);
}
.mySlides.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
.mySlides.active .content {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}

/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */
.dot-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */
.dot.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */
q {
  font-style: italic;
}

/* Add a blue color to the author */
.author {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="content">
      <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
      <p class=" author ">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="content">
      <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
      <p class=" author ">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="content">
      <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
      <p class=" author ">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
    </div>
  </div>



  <a class="prev " onclick="plusSlides(-1) ">❮</a>
  <a class="next " onclick="plusSlides(1) ">❯</a>

</div>

<div class="dot-container ">
  <span class="dot " onclick="currentSlide(1) "></span>
  <span class="dot " onclick="currentSlide(2) "></span>
  <span class="dot " onclick="currentSlide(3) "></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this different from the question you asked yesterday - is that one solved? [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65716305/css-slide-animation-in-quotes-slideshow?noredirect=1#comment116194603_65716305

Comment: No it's not solved.